# How many distinct games are there on a set of cards?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

We say that $G \in P(P(S))$ is a "game" on $S$ if for any $A,B \subseteq S$, we have $A \in G \iff \overline A \notin G$ and $A \subseteq B \implies (A \in G \implies B \in G)$.

Examples:

- The moves in a game of hex, or variants.
- Any non-trivial filter
- Upperwards-closed sets on a boolean algebra

(Note: To play the game, you place cards on a table with elements of $S$. Players take turn taking cards, and if you collect a set of cards in $G$, you win.)

Games $G_1, G_2$ are considered the same if there is some bijection $i : S_1 \to S_2$ such that ${i^\to}^\to(G_1) = G_2$ ($f^\to$ means the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Notation_for_image_and_inverse_image) of $f$, btw).

My question is, if $|S| = k \in \mathbb N$, how many *distinct* games are there on $S$?

Comment: Every non-trivial filter gives a game, and every filter over a finite set is principal. Hence there are at least $2^{|S|}$ games over a finite set $S$.

Comment: The notation $f^\rightarrow$ for *image* of $f$ is a bit confusing.  What did it mean to appy the notation twice(?) to $i$?  Using $G$ for the "set of cards" and $G_1,G_2$ for games is also confusing when you wrote that $G\in P(P(S))$  If $S$ is the entire deck of cards, it seems you've asked for $G$ to be a subset of the subsets of $S$ (interpreting $P$ as power set operation).

Comment: @HanulJeon: Unlike filters, we do not require that the intersection of two elements is in the filter.  OP's Hex example is cogent.  For a reasonable sized board, there are two disjoint paths across the board, which are both winning sets.  Their intersection is the null set, which is losing.  We just need any winning set to prevent the opponent from getting a winning set, but any partition of the universal set into two subsets makes one of the two winning.  We are also working up to isomorphism of relabeling elements.

Comment: @hardmath:  yes, the idea is that you partition $G$ into two disjoint subsets.  Each subset is envisioned as the cards one player draws.  One player should win each partition and having more cards should not change a winning hand into a losing one.

Comment: @RossMillikan you mean $S$?

Comment: @PyRulez:  I have lost the comment I made to you so I don't know how to answer the question.  I now think hex is not such a good example because the winning sets are different for the two players.  As you have defined it I think a winning set for one player should be winning for the other, which is the point that $A \in G \iff \overline A \not \in G$

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry, I meant a win for a chosen player. It doesn't matter which player you choose though.

Comment: @PyRulez:  that will take a substantial edit to the question to clarify.  Now you need a set of subsets that win for player $1$ and a (possibly different) set of subsets that win for player $2$ with the point that every ordered partition into two subsets will result in a win for exactly one player.  Without the asymmetry of winning subsets I was thinking of voting theorems.  Each card is worth a number of points and whoever gets a majority of the points wins.  There are studies of coalitions in multi-person decision making that address this.

Comment: @RossMillikan player 2 wins if player 1 does not win, simple as that.